# C# Hierarchical TreeView display extra level

Tags: c#, treeview, hierarchical

how can i do that...

```
Field
--Crop year <-- property of crop. I want here an extra level for sorting like 2017 or 2018
---Crop
----Fertilizer
----Pesticide
```

... if "Crop year" is a datetime in crop. How can i get the extra level "year"?

```
    <TreeView x:Name="tvFields" Margin="10" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entites:Field}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightGreen">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entites:Crop}" ItemsSource="{Binding PestItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="LightBlue">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entites:Pesticide}" ItemsSource="{Binding PestItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="PaleGreen">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type entites:Fertilizer}" ItemsSource="{Binding FertItems}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Beige">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Should I create an extra class for "Crop year"?

Lyror

Comment: Crop Year has children, so it can't be just a `DateTime`... I'm not sure how you get the above treeview from "Crop year" being a child of "Crop" though, you show it the other way around.

Comment: Crop Year is at the moment no class, its an property of crop. My datatemplate is field --> crop and i want an "extra level" to order it in years